# Logistic Regression(Classification Technique) on Time-dependent Predictors/variables Data

Tags: classification, regression, logistic-regression

I would like to know if I can apply the classification techniques, like say Logistic Regression, to data whose variables/predictors are 'indexed' by time. Or if not, what classification techniques are appropriate to use in these kinds of data.

To give you a clear picture of the problem, say I have a dependent variable Y, whose values are 0 or 1 (for binary case classification), or 1,2,3,...  (for 'multi' classification).

And I have predictor variables which are 'indexed' by time, i.e., X1T1, X1T2,...,X1Tn, X2T1, X2T2,..., X2Tm,....XpTk,

where

```
 X1T1 = values of variable X1 at time 1 (T1)
 X1T2 = values of variable X1 at time 2 (T2) 
    .
    .
 X1Tn = values of variable X1 at time n (Tn)
 X2T1 = values of variable X2 at time 1 (T1)
 X2T2 = values of variable X2 at time 2 (T2)
    .
    .
 X2Tm = values of variable X2 at time m (Tm)
    .
    .
    .
 XpTk = values of variable Xp at time k (Tk)
```

where n,m,k = 1,2,...  (variable time 'index')
          p =1,2,....  (# of predictor variables).

For the data view, we have;

```
 Obs   Y   X1T1   X1T2 ... X1Tn  X2T1  X2T3 ... X2Tm ...  XpTk
  1    .     .      .        .     .     .       .          .
  2    .     .      .        .     .     .       .   ...    .
  .
  .
  .
  N    .     .       .       .     .     .       .   ...    .
```

Can I apply a classification technique, like say, Logistic Regression on these types of data (or other classification techniques for 'multi' category response variable like tree based methods.)  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could use your data to fit Logistic Regression model.
However, the result may not so good because the algorithm would consider each variable independently.

One way to use your data to fit LR model is to make new variables which are okay to be considered that they are independent to each other and keep enough information to represent your original data.

For example)

```
newvar1 = mean(X1T1, X1T2, ..., X1Tn),
newvar2 = sd(X1T1, X1T2, ..., X1Tn),
newvar3 = mean increasing ratio(X1T1, X1T2, ..., X1Tn)
...
```

This way, you can use your data to fit LR model, even though the examples of new variables would not be enough.